# OpenCV: How to draw on just the first frame of a video file and then continue showing the entire video

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am using the opencv-library in python. I have opened an existing video file and wrote a little script that allows me to draw a rectangle anywhere in the video. The problem is: I want to draw this rectangle on the first frame of the video and then leave it there to mark a Region of Interest for me.

I am using `cv2.imshow(winname, frame)` to show my video. Since this runs/shows the video with a very high framerate per second (and I don't want to change that, since my video is pretty long), when I start drawing the rectangle, many frames have already been shown.

Because I think this might be helpful, here is my code so far: 
import cv2

```
#mouse callback function#
def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):

    global pt1, pt2, topLeft_clicked, bottomRight_clicked

    #mouse click
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        #reset
        if topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked:
            topLeft_clicked = False
            bottomRight_clicked = False
            pt1 = (0,0)
            pt2 = (0,0)
        #get coordinates of top left corner
        if not topLeft_clicked:
            pt1 = (x,y)
            topLeft_clicked = True
        #get coordinates of bottom right corner
        elif not bottomRight_clicked:
            pt2 = (x,y)
            bottomRight_clicked = True

#start actual program 

#initially we haven't drawn anything
pt1 = (0,0)
pt2 = (0,0)
topLeft_clicked = False
bottomRight_clicked = False

#capture video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Path to video')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='myName')
cv2.setMouseCallback('myName', draw_rectangle)

firstFrame = True
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    while ret and firstFrame: 
        cv2.imshow('myName', gray_frame)

        if topLeft_clicked: 
            cv2.circle(gray_frame, center=pt1, radius=5, color=(255,0,0), thickness=-1)

        if topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked: 
            cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt1, pt2, (255,0,0), 2)
            firstFrame = False

    cv2.imshow('Estimate_Velocity', gray_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) &0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you want to video stream the video file but want to draw your ROI rectangle, you must do it on every frame. This is because when you use `cv2.imshow` it overwrites the previous frame. An alternative would be to open another window that only shows the 1st frame with the rectangle

Comment: @nathancy: Really? So far I open the video in a named window. And then I am using a callback function (mouse click callback) to draw my rectangle in this window. It works fine and I think I am just drawing the rectangle once. The issue here is that I am done drawing the rectangle when my video has already shown so many frames. I want to draw the rectangle first

Comment: also: I want to draw this rectangle on the first frame already, so that I might be able to use the coordinates pt1 and pt2 to declare an ROI that I can perform certain actions on such as thresholding. Don't know if that works out

Comment: I have just edited my code as to how I thought it should work. But it doesn't. My window opens and python crashes

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented a little bit and found the following solution to my problem:

```
import cv2

#mouse callback function#
def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):

    global pt1, pt2, topLeft_clicked, bottomRight_clicked

    #mouse click
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        #reset
        if topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked:
            topLeft_clicked = False
            bottomRight_clicked = False
            pt1 = (0,0)
            pt2 = (0,0)
        #get coordinates of top left corner
        if not topLeft_clicked:
            pt1 = (x,y)
            topLeft_clicked = True
        #get coordinates of bottom right corner
        elif not bottomRight_clicked:
            pt2 = (x,y)
            bottomRight_clicked = True

#start actual program 

#initially we haven't drawn anything
pt1 = (0,0)
pt2 = (0,0)
topLeft_clicked = False
bottomRight_clicked = False

#capture video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video path')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='myName')
cv2.setMouseCallback('myName', draw_rectangle)

firstFrame = True
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    while firstFrame: 
        cv2.imshow('myName', gray_frame)

        if topLeft_clicked: 
            cv2.circle(gray_frame, center=pt1, radius=5, color=(255,0,0), thickness=-1)

        if topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked: 
            cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt1, pt2, (255,0,0), 2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) &0xFF == ord('c'):
            firstFrame = False
            break

    if topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked: 
        cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt1, pt2, (255,0,0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('myName', gray_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) &0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested this yet, but you can modify your `while` loop break condition:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) &0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
```

to

```
if (topLeft_clicked and bottomRight_clicked):
    if cv2.waitKey(1)  &0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
else:
     # change 1 to 0
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You will need to press a key after you draw the box.

Comment: this doesn't work at all. I have got an error saying my src was empty (for the cv2.cvtColor). Also, I don't think this is going to solve my problem

Comment: Actually my initial idea is similar to yours, I did so several times. I just forgot to put `while` there. Anyway, updated for a different solution.